# Clojure - find longest streak of the same value and its index in a vector

Tags: vector, indexing, clojure, find

In a vector, I want to find the longest streak of a certain value and the starting index of that streak.

Example: (longest-streak-of 1 [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0]) should return {:cnt 3 :at 2}.
The two solutions I found don't seem very clojuresque to me - I'm still learning, so bear with me.
Any answer that provides a more elegant solution would be welcome.

Here's my first attempt:

```
(defn longest-streak-of
  "Returns map with :cnt (highest count of successive n's) and :at (place in arr)"
  [n arr]
  (loop [arr arr streak 0 oldstreak 0 arrcnt 0 place 0]
    (if (and (not-empty arr) (some #(= n %) arr))
      (if (= (first arr) n)
        (recur (rest arr) (+ streak 1) oldstreak (inc arrcnt) place)
        (recur (rest arr) 0 (if (> streak oldstreak)
                              streak oldstreak)
               (inc arrcnt) (if (> streak oldstreak)
                              (- arrcnt streak) place)))
      (if (> streak oldstreak) {:cnt streak :at (- arrcnt streak)}
          {:cnt oldstreak :at place}))))
```

A second solution, which uses clojure.string, but is slower than the one above (I timed both functions and this takes twice as long). I would prefer something like this, hopefully without the use of the string library, as I think it's easier to read and understand:

```
(ns lso.core
  (:require [clojure.string :as s])
  (:gen-class))

(defn lso2 [n arr]
  (let [maxn (apply max (map count (filter #(= (first %) n) (partition-by #(= n %) arr))))]
    {:cnt maxn :at (s/index-of (s/join "" arr) (s/join (repeat maxn (str n))))}))
```

Thank you in advance for any insights!

A new version after reading Alan's answer:

```
(defn lso3
;; This seems to be the best solution yet 
  [n arr]
  (if (some #(= n %) arr)
    (let [parts (partition-by #(= n %) arr)
          maxn (apply max (map count (filter #(= (first %) n) parts)))]
      (loop [parts parts idx 0]
        (if-not (and (= maxn (count (first parts))) (= n (first (first parts))))
          (recur (rest parts) (+ idx (count (first parts))))
          {:cnt maxn :at idx})))
    {:cnt 0 :at 0}))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is what i would propose:

```
user> (->> [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0]
           (map-indexed vector)               ;; ([0 0] [1 0] [2 1] [3 1] [4 1] [5 0] [6 1] [7 0])
           (partition-by second)              ;; (([0 0] [1 0]) ([2 1] [3 1] [4 1]) ([5 0]) ([6 1]) ([7 0]))
           (filter (comp #{1} second first))  ;; (([2 1] [3 1] [4 1]) ([6 1]))
           (map (juxt ffirst count))          ;; ([2 3] [6 1])
           (apply max-key second)             ;; [2 3]
           (zipmap [:at :cnt]))               ;; {:at 2, :cnt 3}

;; {:at 2, :cnt 3}
```

or wrapping it in a function:

```
(defn longest-run [item data]
  (when (seq data)  ;; to prevent exception on apply for empty data
    (->> data
         (map-indexed vector)
         (partition-by second)
         (filter (comp #{item} second first))
         (map (juxt ffirst count))
         (apply max-key second)
         (zipmap [:at :cnt]))))

user> (longest-run 1 [1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 2])
;;=> {:at 0, :cnt 3}
```

**Update**

this one would guard from empty seq at `apply` errors:

```
(defn longest-run [item data]
  (some->> data
           (map-indexed vector)
           (partition-by second)
           (filter (comp #{item} second first))
           (map (juxt ffirst count))
           seq
           (apply max-key second)
           (zipmap [:at :cnt])))
```

Comment: This is the type of answer I was looking for, and very "clojuresque". Triggers an exception, though, if the item is not in the data at all - which can be fixed easily.

Comment: love the solution

Comment: `partition-by` is a great function to use here.  Other parts are hard to read after-the-fact. For example, `(map (juxt ffirst count))` makes me think "What...???" I don't understand how someone can understand this threaded form unless you developed it *with sample data* line-by-line at the repl.

Answer (score 3):

It can be done with no overt loop:

```
user> (defn longest-streak-of [v]
        (->> (map vector v (range)) 
             (partition-by first) 
             (map (fn [r] {:at (second (first r)) :cnt (count r)})) 
             (apply max-key :cnt)))
#'user/longest-streak-of
user> (longest-streak-of [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0])
{:at 2, :cnt 3}
```

The first step pairs each member with its position.  Then `partition-by` blocks the vector off by value (ignoring the position); whereupon we can capture the starting position and length.

I suppose it could be made a little bit more efficient by reversing the last two steps, that is, by doing `max-key` with `count` and forming the `{:at, :cnt}` summary only at the very end.

Comment: This only gives me the longest streak of "anything", but as I said at the start, I need it for a given value, so that I could e.g. get the longest streak of 2s in [0 2 2 0 1 1 1]. Thank you anyways, I learn from all of you.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this list of documention](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template#documentation), especially [the Clojure CheatSheet](https://clojure.org/api/cheatsheet). You are looking for the function `split-with`.

---

### Better answer

I think this version using a helper function to index into the array is simpler than my original answer that chops up the collection:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.schema :as tsk]))

(s/defn streak-info :- [tsk/KeyMap]
  [coll :- tsk/List]
  (let [coll          (vec coll)
        N             (count coll)

        streak-start? (s/fn streak-start? :- s/Bool
                        [idx :- s/Num]
                        (assert (and (<= 0 idx) (< idx N)))
                        (if (zero? idx)
                          true
                          (not= (nth coll (dec idx)) (nth coll idx))))

        result        (reduce
                        (fn [accum idx]
                          (if-not (streak-start? idx)
                            accum
                            (let [coll-remaining (subvec coll idx)
                                  streak-val     (first coll-remaining)
                                  streak-vals    (take-while #(= streak-val %) coll-remaining)
                                  streak-len     (count streak-vals)
                                  accum-next     (append accum {:streak-idx idx
                                                                :streak-len streak-len
                                                                :streak-val streak-val})]
                              accum-next)))
                        []
                        (range N))]
    result))
```

A unit test shows `streak-info` in action:

```
(dotest
  (is= (streak-info [0 0 1 1 0 2 2 2 3])
    [{:streak-idx 0, :streak-len 2, :streak-val 0}
     {:streak-idx 2, :streak-len 2, :streak-val 1}
     {:streak-idx 4, :streak-len 1, :streak-val 0}
     {:streak-idx 5, :streak-len 3, :streak-val 2}
     {:streak-idx 8, :streak-len 1, :streak-val 3}])
  )
```

We then only have to discard all streaks that don't have the desired value `1`, then find the longest via `max-key`.

```
(s/defn longest-ones-streak :- tsk/KeyMap
  [coll :- tsk/List]
  (let [streak-info-all  (streak-info coll)
        streak-info-ones (filter #(= 1 (grab :streak-val %)) streak-info-all)]
    (apply max-key :streak-len streak-info-ones)))

(dotest
  (is= (longest-ones-streak [0 0 1 1 0 2 2 2 3]) {:streak-idx 2, :streak-len 2, :streak-val 1})
  (is= (longest-ones-streak [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 3]) {:streak-idx 5, :streak-len 3, :streak-val 1})
  (is= (longest-ones-streak [0 0 1 1 0 1 1 3 3]) {:streak-idx 5, :streak-len 2, :streak-val 1})
  (is= (longest-ones-streak [0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 3]) {:streak-idx 2, :streak-len 3, :streak-val 1}))
```

Note that in case of a tie, `max-key` uses a "last one wins" technique.

---

### Original Answer

To start, drop any leading `0` elements.  Then, use `split-with` to segment the sequence when you encounter the next `0`.  Count the `1` elements found and save along with the index.

The above needs to be wrapped in a `loop/recur`, `reduce`, or similar.

How to keep track of the index, you say?  The easiest way is to convert your sequence of values to a sequence of pairs (len-2 vectors), where the 1st item of each pair is the index.  An easy way to do that is the `indexed` function [from the Tupelo library](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/20.08.27b/api/tupelo.core#indexed):

```
(defn indexed
  "Given one or more collections, returns a sequence of indexed tuples from the collections:
        (indexed xs ys zs) -> [ [0 x0 y0 z0]
                                [1 x1 y1 z1]
                                [2 x2 y2 z2]
                                ... ]
                                "
  [& colls]
  (apply zip-lazy (range) colls))
```

which simplifies to

```
(defn indexed [vals]
  (mapv vector (range) vals))
```

So, we have an example:

```
(indexed [0 0 1 1 0]) =>
    [[0 0]
     [1 0]
     [2 1]
     [3 1]
     [4 0]]
```

---

### Sample solution with unit tests:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [schema.core :as s]
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    [tupelo.schema :as tsk]))

(s/defn zero-val?
  [pair :- tsk/Pair]
  (let [[idx val] pair] ; destructure the pair into its 2 components
    (zero? val)))

(dotest
  (let [pairs (indexed [0 0 1 1 0])]
    (is= pairs
      [[0 0]
       [1 0]
       [2 1]
       [3 1]
       [4 0]])
    (is (zero-val? [5 0]))
    (isnt (zero-val? [5 1]))))
```

The above shows testing for zeros via a helper function.  Here is how we can find & analyze the first streak in the sequence of indexed pairs:

```
(defn count-streak
  [pairs]
  (let [v1        (drop-while zero-val? pairs)
        [one-pairs remaining-pairs] (split-with #(not (zero-val? %)) v1)
        ones-cnt  (count one-pairs)
        first-pair (first one-pairs)
        idx-begin (first first-pair)]
    ; create a map like
    ;   {:remaining-pairs remaining-pairs
    ;    :ones-cnt        ones-cnt
    ;    :idx-begin       idx-begin}
    (t/vals->map remaining-pairs ones-cnt idx-begin)))

(dotest
  (is= (count-streak (indexed [0 0 1 1 0]))
    {:idx-begin       2
     :ones-cnt        2
     :remaining-pairs [[4 0]]}))
```

Then use `loop/recur` to find the longest streak.

```
(defn max-streak
  [vals]
  (loop [idx-pairs   (indexed vals)
         best-streak {:best-len -1 :best-idx nil}]
    (if (empty? idx-pairs)
      (if (nil? (grab :best-idx best-streak))
        (throw (ex-info "No streak of 1's found" (vals->map best-streak idx-pairs)))
        best-streak)
      (let [curr-streak (count-streak idx-pairs)]
        (t/with-map-vals curr-streak [remaining-pairs ones-cnt idx-begin]
          (t/with-map-vals best-streak [best-len best-idx]
            (if (< best-len ones-cnt)
              (recur remaining-pairs {:best-len ones-cnt :best-idx idx-begin})
              (recur remaining-pairs best-streak))))))))

(dotest
  (throws? (max-streak [0 0 0]) )
  (is= (max-streak [0 0 1 1 0]) {:best-len 2, :best-idx 2})
  (is= (max-streak [0 0 1 1 0 1 0]) {:best-len 2, :best-idx 2})
  (is= (max-streak [0 1 0 1 1 0]) {:best-len 2, :best-idx 3})
  (is= (max-streak [0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0]) {:best-len 3, :best-idx 4}))
```

Comment: Thank you - apparently I wont get around using a loop. "split-with" seems to me just the opposite of "partition-by", which I already used in my second try. So it's all about getting the index of the streak.

Comment: You could refactor the `loop/recur` into `reduce`, which uses `loop/recur` internally.